# jQuery plugin: Validation can't be customized without setting all fields to 'required'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've spent the day looking at [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) by Jörn Zaefferer. I notice that it works fine as long as you call the `validate()` method **without** options. In my little squalid world, as soon as I add options, like `errorPlacement`, I notice that validation ignores `form` fields that are **not** marked `required`. I also notice that many, *many* demos mark *all* fields required---or do not pass options. Am I writing about anything familiar here? Or should I astral project to a parallel universe?

Comment: What are you passing for the `errorPlacement` option?

Comment: Are you using meta to set which fields must be validated?

Comment: emills: I am not using the `meta` option at all.

Comment: crescentfresh: you have something here! there *is* something wrong with my `errorPlacement` handler... any advice from you will be accepted as an answer to my question...

Comment: errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
}//this works fine...

Comment: onfocusout:true throws an error:

>The 'charCode' property of a keyup event should not be used.
>The value is meaningless.
>validator.settings["on" + event.type].call is not a function

This error dates back to 3/2008: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/e33d9d316530be1d

Answer (score 2):

*Note: This is to close the question out and provide info to resolve this to the next person finding the question since the OP has resolve the issue.*

If there are *any* errors in the options, it will act the same as ignoring the fields, this isn't the validation plugin behavior per se, but rather how javascript works overall...any errors and it blows up (in mosts cases).

Double check all your options and use either [Chrome's tools](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html) or [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there are any script errors at all.  Judging from your question, this seems the most likely culprit, fixing any errors in your options/`errorPlacement` will eliminate the onstacle in making the validation plugin work.

Also for testing, it's very helpful to use the [`debug` option on the validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  //other options
  debug: true
});
```

This prevents the form from actually submitting, allowing you to tweak the validation much faster.